# How to define variable in function Pascal

Tags: function, pascal, freepascal

```
function F(x:real) : real;
begin
  F := a*power(x,2);
end;
```

Guys, I need help.I am using Lazarus with form and I want to make a function with variable 'a' there. Variable a is an input just like `a:= StrToInt(Edit1.Text);`
Then how to define a there?

Answer (score 1):

You should make `a` be an argument to the function.

```
function F(a: Integer; x: real): real;
begin
  F := a*power(x,2);
end;
```

Further, using `power` for integer exponents is expensive and not terribly accurate. Use direct multiplication, in this case you can make use of `sqr`.

```
function F(a: Integer; x: real): real;
begin
  F := a*sqr(x);
end;
```

Now, when you call the function you can use `StrToInt(Edit1.Text)` to obtain the value of `a`, which you pass on to the function. Or indeed you can use some other means to obtain `a`.

All of this is to avoid your arithmetic functions requiring knowledge of your UI.